# Registration Account in my WebSite (Spring Security + HTML)

Tags: java, html, spring, web, spring-security

I created a project (website). Admin or user can enter the website through the username and password. Now when I go to the site through the admin, I can create a new account. Creating a new account, I can give him a username and password + role (admin or user). You can see, I wrote everything correctly, maybe something is missing.

AddUser.JSP

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <title>Home</title>

    </head> 
    <body>

        <div class="add">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>

            <br>
            <center>
                <h1>${headerMessage}</h1>

                <form:form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/addUser" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <table>

                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Name">Name</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><label path="Surname">Surname</label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="surname"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><select name="select" size="3" multiple>
                                    <option selected value="s1">Admin</option>
                                    <option value="s2">User</option>

   </select></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="Role"/>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form:form>
            </center>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

AdminDecorator.JSP

```
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">


    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"><span>Главная</span></a></li>

            <li class="dropdown"><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/allStudents"><span>Students</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/allStudents"><span>Student List</span></a></li>
                    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN') || hasRole('USER')">
                    <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addStudent"><span>Add Student</span></a></li>
                    </sec:authorize>
                    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')"> 
                    <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addUser"><span>Add User</span></a></li>
                    </sec:authorize>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a><span>О нас </span></a></li> 
            <sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()"> 
            <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout"><span>Выйти</span></a></li>
             </sec:authorize>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

        <sitemesh:write property='body'/>
    <jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/template/admintemplate.jsp"/>  
    </body>
</html>
```

AdminController.JAVA

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/allStudentsAdmin")
    public ModelAndView allStudentsForUser() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudentsAdmin");
        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/allStudentsAdmin");
        return mv;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("adminEditStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
            @RequestParam("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));
        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/errors";
        }

        return "redirect:/admin/allStudentsAdmin";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/addStudentAdmin")
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudentAdmin");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudentAdmin")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
        }
        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/admin/allStudentsAdmin";
    }

      @GetMapping(value = "/addUser")
    public ModelAndView displayAddUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudentAdmin");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addUser")
    public String saveNewUser(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
            @RequestParam("role") @NonNull String role)

            throws IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);


        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/admin/allStudentsAdmin";
    }

}
```

User.JAVA

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    private String role;



    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

     public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }




    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", surname='" + surname + '\'' +
                ", role='" + role + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
```

UserService

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.service;

import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.User;

import java.io.IOException;


public interface UserService {





    boolean saveUser(User user);



    User updateUser(String name, String surname, String role, User targetUser) throws IOException;

}
```

UserServiceImpl

package adil.java.schoolmaven.service;

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Value("${storage.location}")

    private String storageLocation;

    private UserRepository repository;

    public UserServiceImpl() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository repository) {
        super();
        this.repository = repository;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean saveUser(User user) {
        try {
            repository.save(user);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public User updateStudent(String name, String surname, String role, User targetUser)
            throws IOException {

        if (name != null && !name.equals(targetUser.getName())) {

            targetUser.setName(name);

        }

        if (surname != null && !surname.equals(targetUser.getSurname())) {

            targetUser.setSurname(surname);

        }

         if (role != null && !role.equals(targetUser.getRole())) {

            targetUser.setRole(role);

        }



        return targetUser;

    }



}
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>adil.java.schoolmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>SchoolMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SchoolMaven</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>8.0.15</mysql.connector.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet Spec -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sitemesh</groupId>
            <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>           
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency>   
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>           
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> 
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>           
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>


          <dependency>
    <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>

    <exclusions>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
      <exclusion> 
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions> 

  </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SchoolMaven</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version> <!-- or whatever current version -->
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did I write everything right? I have it not work

Comment: do you use maven build tool...? then share your pom file

Comment: i add question pom file